# Can I use Grove LCD on raspberry pi without Grove Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, lcd, grovepi+

I'd like to use the [a Grove RGB LCD](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-LCD_RGB_Backlight/) on a raspberry Pi. I would like to plug it directly with minimal circuitry.

It's a cheap RGB LCD that use I2C. There's raspberry pi librairies (Python and C)... but it's supposed to be plugged to a Grove Pi wich is more expensive but you don't have to.

Has anyone done that already ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should post this at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ instead. Stackoverflow should be programming related with no open-ended question.

Comment: Well ! I finally did it. I used a voltage level converter.
RPI 5v directly to grove rgb vcc,
sda, scl and gnd through the voltage level converter. It works but it's not stable (yet ?). Many errors but it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RGB LCD uses a 5V rail.  The Raspberry Pi uses a 3V3 rail.  If you're going to connect them, you'll need a level converter chip in between them.  The [GrovePi](http://dexterindustries.com/grovepi) provides the level conversion, but if you're not going to use the GrovePi for [the Raspberry Pi](https://www.dexterindustries.com/shop/raspberry-pi-3/), you'll need to find your own chip or you risk damaging both the Raspberry Pi and the LCD.